# how to set delivery option in Teams incoming webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm trying to send a message to Teams channel via incoming webhook like this

```
curl --location 'https://vivij.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/asdff1234' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "text": "my test message"
}'
```

now I want to set the delivery option for this message ( **Important, Urgent**)
how can I do that ?

is it possible to do with webhook if so what's the parameter name and value ?

couldn't find anything in docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not supported, we cannot set priority(Important, Urgent) to the messages send via incoming webhook adaptive cards.

Please note that this is possible via sending a [chat message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) using Graph. You need to make use of "importance" property. The possible values are: normal, high, urgent.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

[image]

[image]